# Suppose $A$ is a square matric, not necessarily symmetric , and that $A+A^T$ is positive semidefinite , Then

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ is a square matric, not necessarily symmetric , and that  $A+A^T$ is positive semidefinite , Then

1. show that $x^TAx\ge 0$ for all $x$.
2. show that $I+A$ is non singular
3. define $S=(I-A)(I+A)^{-1}$ . Show that $I-S^TS$ is positive semidefinite.
4. show that $\|S\|_2\le 1$

Sorry I have no idea where to start.. can you please any idea

Comment: What is your work?

Comment: Ok, do you know that any matrix can be represented as sum of symmetric and anti symmetric matrices? Also for a anti symmetric matrix $A$ , $x^{T}Ax$ is always $0$.

Comment: @Alearner..yes ik sir

Comment: @angryavian. i do try sir

Comment: @angryavian  .....this can't be zero if $x \ne 0$ and i have tried first 2

Comment: @angryavian how does it relate to whether $I+A$ singular or not?

Comment: There is non singular matrices such that $x^{T} A x =0$ for some $x$

Comment: @learner you can think , $A$ will be similar with some $C+D$ , where $C$ symmetric, $D$ antisymmetric, and Now since , $C$ is positive semi definite , so, it have non negative eigenvalue, and as $D$ is antisymmetric, it must have $0$ or purely imaginary as Eigen value, hence there is no $-1$ as eigenvalue of $A$ , so, $I+A$ non singular.

Comment: Here are hints for first two. 

1. Show $x^TAx = x^TA^Tx$ 
2. If $x = -Ax$ for some non-zero $x$, then $x^TAx < 0 $

Answer (score 2):

Put $x(t)=e^{At}x_0$ for any $x_0$. Then, the product rule gives $\partial_t||x(t)||^2=x(t)^\top(A+A^\top)x(t)$, while component-wise differentiation gives $\partial_t\sum_i x_i(t)^2=2\sum_i x_i(t)x_i'(t)=2x(t)^\top Ax(t)$. Thus
$$ 2x(t)^\top Ax(t)=x(t)^\top(A+A^\top)x(t) \ge 0$$
for all $t$, in particular, for $t=0$ this gives $x_0^\top Ax_0\ge 0$. Use this to show that $I+A$ is positive definite and hence nonsingular.

By the positivity of $A+A^\top$ we have
$$x^\top(I-A^\top)(I-A)x=x^\top(I-(A+A^\top)+A^\top A)x\le x^\top (I+A^\top)(1+ A)x$$ and thus, letting $x = (I+A)^{-1}y$ yields $||Sy||^2\le y^\top (I+A^\top)^{-1}(I+A^\top)(I+A)(I+A)^{-1}y=||y||^2$. This proves 4 which implies 3.